# ConcurrentModificationException в java

Tags: java, исключения, обработка-ошибок, итераторы

Пробовал найти статьи в интернете, но, в основном, там речь идёт о том, как с этим бороться.
Хотелось бы получить базовые знания о том, что это, в каких ситуациях возникает, как избежать и т.д.

Comment: [Документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) пробовали читать?

Comment: Поищите информацию о Fail-Fast и Fail-Safe итераторах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один кусок кода дороже тысячи слов...

Если вам интересно, в каких ситуациях возникает, посмотрите в исходниках. Например, [java.util.ArrayList](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) и [java.util.AbstractList](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java)

Если коротко, то у каждого объекта типа `AbstractList` есть счётчик `modCount`. Каждая операция, которая изменяет список, такие как добавление элементов, удаление элементов, очистка списка, и т.п., этот счетчик инкрементирует.

Те операции, которым нужно, чтобы список в ходе выполнения операции не менялся, например операция `equals`, сохраняют значение `modCount` до начала выполнения операции, и в конце операции обязательно сравнивают с текущим значением `modCount`. Если значения не совпали, то выбрасывается `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Самый простой пример - вычисление хэш-кода:

```
    public int hashCode() {
        int expectedModCount = modCount;
        int hash = hashCodeRange(0, size);
        checkForComodification(expectedModCount);
        return hash;
    }
```

Метод `checkForComodification` выбросит исключение, если текущее значение `modCount` не совпадёт с `expectedModCount`.

Поищите по тексту классов выражение `modCount++` - вы найдёте все те места, в которых меняется состояние объекта. Все те места, где ожидается неизменность объекта в ходе выполнения операции, содержат вызов `checkForComodification`.

Как избежать?

Простой, но дорогой в эксплуатации способ - обернуть все операции с коллекцией в `RWLock`. Сложный и недостоверный способ - прогнать вашу программу через статический анализатор и поискать race conditions. Если не найдёт, то скрестить пальцы и верить, что коллизий не будет :)